# What's the proper way of deleting versioned data from an SDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning

I haven't really read this anywhere.

What is the proper way of deleting versioned data from an SDE geodatabase to make sure nothing is left behind in the A & D tables?

Do I need to unversion the data before I delete it? Do I need to remove the user versions? Or does it matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unversioning removes the A and D tables associated with a single versioned feature class.  Any edits not reconciled and posted to the base table will be lost, which appears to be your goal.

Comment: Okay, but what if I were to not unversion the data and delete it. Would it still do the same thing? Or could there possibly be tables left stranded out there?

Comment: If you DROP the A & D tables without unversioning, you corrupt your geodatabase.  If you use ArcGIS to delete the versioned feature classes it will clean up the instance correctly.